# Определение причин невыполнения запроса

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, запрос, linux

Есть процедура, читающая из базы данных значения и записывающая данные в ArrayList-ы, которые также записываютмся в файлы. В результате выполнения программы отладочные файлы оказываются пустыми. Подскажите в чем дело Родключение к базе данных как я понимаю происходит поскольку файлы из блока catch SQLException не создаются. Почему не выполняется запрос? Как выяснить причину этого, если дело в этом. Запрос выдает результаты в pgAdmin 3.

```
    public void readUsingDataFromDatabase(ArrayList<String> therms, ArrayList<Integer> idOfFiles, ArrayList<Integer> countThermsInFiles, String[] url, String[] user, String[] password, int[] countFiles)
    {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;        
        String currentFile;
        int countThermsInFile;
        int countRows=0;
        try
        {
           PrintWriter debugFileForBlock = null;
           try
           {
                debugFileForBlock = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/paramsinreadusingdata.txt"));
           }
           catch(FileNotFoundException e)
           {
                System.exit(0);
           }
           debugFileForBlock.println(url[0]);
           debugFileForBlock.println(user[0]);
           debugFileForBlock.println(password[0]);
           debugFileForBlock.close();           
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url[0], user[0], password[0]);
                    st = con.createStatement();
                    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT a.value, c.value, c.id FROM therms a INNER JOIN therm_occurs b ON b.therm_id = a.id INNER JOIN fs_entries c ON b.file_id = c.id ORDER BY a.value, c.value, c.id");
            rs.first();
            therms.add(rs.getString(1));
            countThermsInFile=1; 
            currentFile=rs.getString(2); 
            idOfFiles.add(rs.getInt(3)); 
           PrintWriter debugFilePoint1 = null;
           try
           {
                debugFilePoint1 = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/point1.txt"));
           }
           catch(FileNotFoundException exc1)
           {
                System.exit(0);
           }
           debugFilePoint1.println("Пройдена точка после позиционирования на первой записи");
           debugFilePoint1.close();             
            countFiles[0]=1;
            countRows=1;
           PrintWriter debugFilePoint2 = null;
           try
           {
                debugFilePoint2 = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/point2.txt"));
           }
           catch(FileNotFoundException exc2)
           {
                System.exit(0);
           }
           debugFilePoint2.println("Пройдена точка после инициалиазции количества файлов и строк запроса единицами");
           debugFilePoint2.close();             
            while (rs.next()) 
            { 
                if (currentFile!=rs.getString(2)) 
                    {
                        countThermsInFiles.add(countThermsInFile); 
                        countFiles[0]+=1; 
                        currentFile=rs.getString(2); 
                        countThermsInFile=1; 
                        idOfFiles.add(rs.getInt(3)); 
                    }
                else
                    {
                        countThermsInFile+=1; 
                    }; 
                therms.add(rs.getString(1));
                countRows+=1;
            };
            countThermsInFiles.add(countThermsInFile);
           PrintWriter debugFilePoint3 = null;
           try
           {
                debugFilePoint3 = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/point2.txt"));
           }
           catch(FileNotFoundException exc3)
           {
                System.exit(0);
           }
           debugFilePoint3.println("Пройден цикл обхода по результатам запроса");
           debugFilePoint3.close();  
        }
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
           PrintWriter debugFileForException = null;
              PrintWriter outFile = null;                   
           try
           {
                outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/messagefromexception.txt"));
                debugFileForException = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/exception.txt"));
           }
           catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
           {
                System.exit(0);
           }
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsString=sw.toString();
           debugFileForException.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
           debugFileForException.println(exceptionAsString);
           debugFileForException.close();           
            //System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            //StringWriter sw = new StringWrite();
            //e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            //String exceptionAsString=sw.toString();

        }
       PrintWriter debugFileForRs = null;
       PrintWriter debugFileForTherms = null;
       PrintWriter debugFileForIds = null;
       PrintWriter debugFileForCounts = null;
       try
       {
            debugFileForRs = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/resultset.txt"));
       }
       catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
            System.exit(0);
            }
       debugFileForRs.println(countRows);
       debugFileForRs.close();
       try
       {
            debugFileForTherms = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/therms.txt"));
       }
       catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
            System.exit(0);
            }
       for (int i=0; i<therms.size(); i++)
       {     
            debugFileForTherms.println(therms.get(i));
       }
       debugFileForTherms.close();
           try
       {
            debugFileForIds = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/idoffiles.txt"));
       }
       catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
            System.exit(0);
            }
       for (int i=0; i<idOfFiles.size(); i++)
       {     
            debugFileForIds.println(idOfFiles.get(i));
       }
       debugFileForIds.close();
           try
       {
            debugFileForCounts = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/countthermsinfiles.txt"));
       }
       catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
            System.exit(0);
            }
       for (int i=0; i<countThermsInFiles.size(); i++)
       {     
            debugFileForCounts.println(countThermsInFiles.get(i));
       }
       debugFileForCounts.close();
    }
```

Comment: выполните запрос вручную и посмотрите что за проблема

Comment: @misha-nesterenko Запрос выдает результаты в pgAdmin 3 (забыл сказать). Возможно не работает в программе.

Comment: посмотрите на какой строке падает, что за исключение, а то можно только гадать в чем проблема

Answer (score 1):

А нельзя никак пройти отладчиком? У вас что ни строка то вопрос. Далеко ходить не буду и приведу примеры:

1) Вложенные друг в друга `try-catch` блоки, не то чтобы этого нельзя делать, но в данном контектсте они бессмысленные, вместо:

```
try {
   try {
   }
   catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
   }
}
catch(SQLException sqe) {
}
```

Можно и нужно писать:

```
try {
}
catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
}
catch(SQLException sqe) {
}
```

А еще лучше:

```
try {
}
catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
}
catch(SQLException sqe) {
}
catch(Exception e) {
}
```

2) Когда пишете:

```
rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT ..."); 
rs.first();
```

Это как-то смело... `RecordSet` вполне может вернуться `null` или если `RecordSet` пустой, то при вызове `rs.first()` - вся конструкция может тупо завалиться набок...

3) Почему не закрываете за собой коннекты, рекордсеты?!

4) Ну и в третьих самое важное: научитесь делить задачу на мелкие куски: *слон большой, его надо есть кусочками*. Например, почему бы не запустить отдельно запрос с командной строки и проверить - вообще работает или нет? Или если вся процедура не работает, попробуйте закомментировать часть кода, ну и т.д.